# Передача параметров в мутацию vuex с нагрузкой

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Играюсь с небольшими приложениями, использующими vuex, возник вопрос о том, как правильно передавать event в vuex.

Вот какой у меня пример. У меня есть канвас, рядом с ним высвечиваются координаты курсора над канвасом. Всё работает в классическом варианте:

```
<div>
  <canvas id="cnv" height="300" width="600" v-on:mousemove="coord"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="status_bar">
  <div>X: {{ coordX }}</div>
  <div>Y: {{ coordY }}</div>
</div>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Main",
  data() {
    return {
      coordX: 0,
      coordY: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    coord(event) {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv");
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

      this.coordX = event.clientX - rect.left;
      this.coordY = event.clientY - rect.top;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Однако, когда я попробовал перенести код на vuex - не удаётся из action вызвать мутацию с параметрами:

```
<template>
  <div class="Main">
    <div>
      <canvas id="cnv" height="300" width="600" v-on:mousemove="coord"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="status_bar">
      <div>X: {{ $store.state.cur.X }}</div>
      <div>Y: {{ $store.state.cur.Y }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Main",
    methods: mapActions([
    'coord'
  ]),
};
</script>
```

Файл store/index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
  cur: {
    X: 0,
    Y: 20
  },
}

const mutations = {
  coord(pos) {
    state.cur.X = pos.X;
    state.cur.Y = pos.Y;
  }
}

const actions = {
  coord({ commit }, event) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv");
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var pos = {
      X: event.clientX - rect.left,
      Y: event.clientY - rect.top,
    };

    console.log(pos);
    //commit('coord');
    //commit('coord', pos);
    //store.commit('coord', pos);
    //store.dispatch('coord', pos);
  }
}

const getters = {}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
})
```

Там после console.log закомментированные строки - мои неудачные попытки вызова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перечитываю [документацию](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/actions.html) по мутациям и действиям, однако не понимаю, как собрать вызов в целое.

> в файле main.js, подключили store? Кроме того, в коде не видно, где Вы диспатчете действие

Подключил:

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Comment: в файле `main.js`, подключили store? Кроме того, в коде не видно, где Вы диспатчете действие

Comment: @Дмытрык Mea culpa, думал что достаточно привёл инфы. Обновил вопрос, добавив про что спрашиваете. И не знаю, нужно ли ещё это... но проект создавал через стандартное `vue init webpack`

Answer (score 2):

Ага, я разобрался сам.

В мутации нужно указать state и потом параметры:

```
const mutations = {
  coord(state, pos) {
    state.cur.X = pos.X;
    state.cur.Y = pos.Y;
  }
}
```

И вызывать так:

```
const actions = {
  coord({ commit }, event) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("cnv");
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var pos = {
      X: event.clientX - rect.left,
      Y: event.clientY - rect.top,
    };

    commit('coord', pos);
  }
}
```

После чего всё работает так же, как и без vuex.

Comment: не успел написать... только что и я разобрался)